# How can I align this div in left using CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

[link](http://ch-consulting.ro/)

I want to left align this div. I attached bellow a pic to understand what i want to do.

[image]

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="alt-service-grid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">//SOME CODE HTML</div>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">//SOME CODE HTML</div>
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="alt-service-wrap">
                //SOME CODE HTML
                </div>
                <div class="alt-service-wrap">
                 //SOME CODE HTML
                </div>
                <div class="alt-service-wrap">
                //This is myDiv,align-left
                </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This site is made with Wordpess and I use a paid template.
I have tried at last div to add the fallow html code `float:left;`

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add class="pull-left"

Comment: You tried? Not work ... at least to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to place it after **row** class `div`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="alt-service-grid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">//SOME CODE HTML</div>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">//SOME CODE HTML</div>
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="alt-service-wrap">
                //SOME CODE HTML
                </div>
                <div class="alt-service-wrap">
                 //SOME CODE HTML
                </div>

       </div>
   </div>
                <div class="alt-service-wrap">
                //This is myDiv,align-left
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the place of your div and make it in the first `col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3` div:

```
<div class="alt-service-grid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
           <div class="alt-service-wrap">
                //SOME CODE HTML
           </div>
           <div class="alt-service-wrap">
               //This is Your Div
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">//SOME CODE HTML</div>
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">//SOME CODE HTML</div>
   </div>
</div>
```